# Find all the words used to search and click on a phrase

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, text

I have a database of different letter/words people use to search for something online. Since we track what they type, we have all the letters/words they typed in order to get to a phrase using the autocomplete functionality which exists on our site. We have data which looks like this:

```
Time            Phrase             Clicked
6/17/20 13:03   Micr    
6/17/20 13:03   Micorosoft  
6/17/20 13:03   Micor   
6/17/20 13:03   Microsft    
6/17/20 13:03   Microsoft            TRUE
6/17/20 13:33   Brex    
6/17/20 13:43   los 
6/17/20 14:01   ama 
6/17/20 14:01   Amazon               TRUE
6/17/20 14:03       
6/17/20 14:03   u   
6/17/20 14:03   ujo 
6/17/20 14:03   upjn    
6/17/20 14:03   upjoh   
6/17/20 14:03   upjohn               TRUE
```

As you see above, someone wanted to search for Microsoft, so he started typing that. He did miss-spell it a bunch of times but was able to find the match which the autocomplete suggested. The one he clicked has the "click" category marked as "True".
I want to produce a list of all the letters/words which a user is typing (even the misspelled ones) to get to the end phrase. For Microsoft it captures all the phrase shown above. Similarly for Amazon and upjohn. **Since, phrase such as "Brex" and "los" didn't result in a click, we can discard them.** How do I implement this in python?

In the end database looks like this:

```
Completed Phrase    Letter/Words    
  Microsoft           Micr
                      Micorosoft
                      Micor
                      Microsft
                      Microsoft
    Amazon            ama
                      Amazon
    Upjohn            u
                      ujo
                      upjn
                      upjoh
                      Upjohn
```

Comment: *Since, phrase such as "Brex" and "los" didnt result in a click, we can discard them.*: there is nothing in your table that indicates that these did not result in a click. As far as the data is concerned, they relate to the following click on Amazon. Please explain how we can discard them.

Comment: i mean, the reason i think they are not related is because, they dont relate to amazon, in terms of spelling.